# How to know if a point is locate at outer circle?

Tags: geometry, pythagorean

Having a circle with the centre (xc,yc) with the radius r how to know whether a point (xp,yp) is locate at the outer circle which following in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inner circle has radius `r` and outer circle has radius `R`, then you can check whether point lies in the ring using comparison of squared distances:

```
 dd = (xp - xc)^2 + (yp - yc)^2
 if (dd <= R^2) and (dd >= r^2) then 
    point is in the ring
```